# ngrx/store metareducers vs META_REDUCERS

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular8, ngrx-store

I'm trying to figure out what is the difference between those two ways of providing `metaReducers` to `NgModule`: in imports array: `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers })` and second approach is to not include `metaReducers` in `forRoot` method but add it in providers array like: `{ provider: META_REDUCER, useFactoru: myCustomFuncToGetMetaReducers }`.

What is the difference between first and second approach?

Answer (score 0):

A little bit contrived but: A (lazy-loaded) module could inject MetaReducers via the injection token when it is loaded without having to create a `StoreModule.forFeature` in it.

When could be this the case? If you just want to provide the MetaReducer and no other reducer logic or feature logic.

Cheers Chris

Comment: I don't understand the explanation , but I am also looking for answer of similar question. Chris , Could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

The `META_REDUCERS` token is aimed for internal NgRx meta reducers or libraries.
An example, the runtime checks provided by NgRx.

A 3rd party library could use add a meta reducer, so you only have to import the module instead of adding the metareducer yourself to the metareducers option.

Comment: Not entirely sure what do you mean by that. Can you elaborate?